# Serving static files while running Django&mod_wsgi on Apache 2.2

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, static-files

I have changed my Apache 2.2's httpd.conf

```
#Serve static files
Alias /static/ "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\static\"
<Directory "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\static">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

#Start mod_wsgi as default handler
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\django.wsgi"

<Directory "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and my app can be successfully run, only the static files cannot be accessed, a 404 is thrown by Django

However, if I change this line

```
Alias /static/ "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\static\"
```

into

```
Alias /static/ "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\static"
```

the index page of the static folder can be seen, but the files cannot be reached. When I checked Apache's error log at this time, I found something like this:

```
File does not exist "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\staticmy_static_file.txt"
```

it seems there's a "\" missing, anyone has an idea on fixing this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django and is an Apache issue: Django does not server static file in a production environnement, as stated in the documentation. Please change your title accordingly.

Comment: This is not related to your question but if <Directory "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog"> somebody from outside your server to access your Python code, you should remove this immidiatly as it is a huge security issue.

Comment: @e-satis I've moved my django.wsgi into E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\apache and changed <Directory "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\apache">

Comment: Try not using backward slashes. Apache quite happily uses forward slashes on Windows. This saves the confusion of whether a backslash acts as an escape character in certain circumstances and not others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the trailing slash from the alias itself:

```
Alias /static "E:\Python\Django\carlsblog\static"
```

---

**Update (2015)**: This answer is from 2011.  Currently, it is considered a much better practice to use gunicorn + nginx to serve django apps.

Comment: In my sitation (windows) I did have to do a whack like so - Alias /static "D:/Tidal/static/" having reverse whacks didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are your templates OK?  Check your generated html using `View Source` in your browser.

Comment: It's nothing to do with my templates,  I'm trying to get the static files directly to test if my config is right to serve static files